# I am trying to figure out why my anagram function is getting the wrong output

Tags: python, anagram

The parameter is a list of words. Desired output a list of grouped anagrams.

```
def anagrams(lst):
    d = {}
    while len(lst) > 0:
        pop = lst.pop()
        d[pop] = d.get(pop, [])
        d[pop].append(pop)
        for word in lst:
            perm = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(pop)]
            if word in perm:
                d[pop].append(word)
                lst.remove(word)
    anagram = d.values()
    return list(anagram)

print(anagrams(['eat', 'ate', 'done', 'tea', 'soup', 'node']))
```

--- Console output... (wrong output) ---

```
 [['node', 'done'], ['soup'], ['tea', 'eat'], ['ate']]
```

--- Desired output ---

```
 [['eat', 'ate', 'tea], ['done', 'node'], ['soup']]
```

Things I've tried
My pseudocode when pop = 'tea' in the while loop

```
pop = ‘tea’
lst = [‘eat’,’ate’]

for ‘eat’ in lst:
    perm = perm of [tea]
    if eat in perm (true)
        d[tea].append(‘eat’)  # d[tea] = [tea, eat]
        lst = [‘ate’]

for ‘ate’ in lst:
    perm = perm of [tea]
    if ‘ate’ in perm: (should be yes)
        d[tea].append(ate) -> d[tea] = [tea, eat, ate]
        lst.remove['ate'] -> lst = []
```

**This is not the case**

Comment: please fix code formatting and indentation

Comment: ugh.. I had it all formatted for you ..

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: While you're at it.. make sure you have the proper character for single quotes. IDK what you were using before, backticks?

Comment: yup backticks @T

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea, but you are making this a little too hard. You can create your dictionary so the keys are the sorted letters of the word. This will make `ate` and `eat` both end up in the same place under the key `aet`. With this you avoid calculating permutations, it's only a couple lines, and it's fast:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def anagrams(words):
    lookup = defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        lookup["".join(sorted(word))].append(word)
    return list(lookup.values())


anagrams(['eat', 'ate', 'done', 'tea', 'soup', 'node'])
# [['eat', 'ate', 'tea'], ['done', 'node'], ['soup']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/group-anagrams-in-python)

```
def anagrams(strs):
  result = {}
  for i in strs:
      x = "".join(sorted(i))
      result.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
  return list(result.values())

print(anagrams(['eat', 'ate', 'done', 'tea', 'soup', 'node']))

#Out: [['eat', 'ate', 'tea], ['done', 'node'], ['soup']]
```

**Explanation**

[Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/group-anagrams-in-python)

> To solve this, we will follow these steps
>
> ```
> Define result as map 
>
> for i in string array
>    x := x and join, sorted string of i 
>    if x in result 
>      insert i in result[x] 
>    else result[x] := [i] 
>
> return values of result as list
> ```